# I want to customize the_posts_navigation function by replacing prev and next with images

Tags: functions, customization, pagination, terms

Hie,

I am currently trying to customize the function 'the_posts_navigation' of Wordpress because I would like to let appear only "previous" and "next" (which I want to replace by icons of arrow in SVG), would you have a track to help me?

Here is a piece of the code:

```
the_posts_navigation( array(
                    'mid_size' => 1,
                    'prev_text' => __( '<<', 'textdomain' ),
                    'next_text' => __( '>>', 'textdomain' ),
                    'prev_next'          => true,
                    'in_same_term'       => true,
                    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'cm' ) . ' </span>',
                ) );
```

Et voici le bout de code que j'aimerais intégrer à la fonction native "the_posts_pagination" de Wordpress pour remplacer le "previous" et le "next" par des icones en SVG:

```
<a class="cover--nav-prev" href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevPostID); ?>">
                <span class="cover--nav-label"><?php _e('Recette précédente', 'marque'); ?></span>
                <svg class="icon icon-arrow-prev" role="presentation" focusable="false"><use xlink:href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/symbol-defs.svg#icon-arrow-prev"></use></svg>
            </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put svg text right in the prev_text and next_text.

To make it a little more readable here I've broken it up and prepared the SVG markup first. I am only show you the "prev" link but the "next" would work the same way.

```
$prev_label = "<span class='cover--nav-label'>" . _e('Recette précédente', 'marque') . "</span>";

$prev_arrow = "<svg class='icon icon-arrow-prev' role='presentation' focusable='false'><use xlink:href='" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/symbol-defs.svg#icon-arrow-prev'></use></svg>";

$prev_text = $prev_label . $prev_arrow;

the_post_navigation( array(
  'prev_text' => $prev_text
) );
```

Note that the_post_navigation will be wrapping your prev_text (and next_text) within the  tag and applying the appropriate link target, so you don't include that part here.

Comment: Thank you. If you are satisfied with the answer please mark it as accepted so that others know your question has a solution.